# Brownian motion from Newton's Second law

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Can someone please explain the step from 1.16 and 1.17, please? I am trying to understand the underlying mathematics, but am stumped.

[equation of motion for the Brownian particle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a5grj.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From (1.16), multiplying by $x$ you get that:
$$ x\cdot m\frac{d^2x}{dt^2} = -x\cdot \gamma \frac{dx}{dt} + x\cdot f_r(t)$$

Now, by the chain rule and the product rule: $$\frac{1}{2}\frac{d^2x^2}{dt^2} = \frac{d}{dt}(\frac{1}{2}\frac{dx^2}{dt}) = \frac{d}{dt}(x\frac{dx}{dt}) = x \frac{d^2x}{dt^2} + (\frac{dx}{dt})^2 .$$

Also by the chain rule,
$$\frac{dx^2}{dt} = 2x\frac{dx}{dt}.$$

Substituting these into the LHS and RHS of the relation above, you get (1.17).

Comment: Something may be missing in the second line, in the middle term.  What is $\frac{d}{dx} \left( x \frac{d}{dx} \right)$?

Comment: That was a typo that I edited a few minutes ago. Is it not showing up? It was meant to be $\frac{d}{dt}(x\frac{dx}{dt})$.

Comment: Refreshed the page, and now it is showing up!  Thanks!